# How wait a promise before execute the rest of code

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my service I search for a variable in my localstorage:

```
constructor(private storage: Storage) {

    this.storage.get('value').then(
                (val) => {
                    this.value = val;
                },
                () => {
                    this.value = 'no value';
                });
    }
```

The problem is that I have a method:

```
getVariable(){
    return this.value;
}
```

This method should return the value. But the value is not set at the beginning. How can I do that the getVariable wait until promise in constructor resolved is?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some context for your problem. If you use this value for string interpolation you can just wait for change detection to fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route resolver or rely on OnInit interface.
If you absolutly need to wait for the promise to be resolved then use a resolver.

Here is an example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private storage: MyStorageService,) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<any> {

    return this.storage.get('value').then(
            (val) => {
                return val;
            },
            () => {
               return 'no value';
            });
  }
}
```

In your routing configuration, link your route to the resolver as follow:

```
 {
    path: 'myyPath',
    component: MyComponent,
    resolve: {
      myResolvedValue: MyResolver // myResolvedValue is the key under which you'll be able to retrieved the resolved value. You can put whichever key you want
    },
  },
```

And finally, bind route data changes into your component (note that you must implement OnInit) :

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.value= data['myResolvedValue'];
    });
  }
```